# Redirect specific requests to login page and throw 401 for others in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have a spring boot application with few restful endpoints. This application also serves the html pages and js files developed using React.

I have implemented user authentication to this application using the spring oauth2. When the user is not authenticated, the requests are redirected to login page, either it be a request to html page or REST endpoint. But I don't want the requests to REST endpoints to return redirect response to login page but just 401.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you define a custom authentication entry point like this.

For every unauthorized requests, they will land in your custom entrypoint.

Here you can add any custom logic to check only what type of REST request you wish to answer with 401.

```
public class AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint extends
    LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final RequestMatcher requestMatcher = new ELRequestMatcher(
            "hasHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest')");

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        super();
    }

    public AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if(isPreflight(request)){
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
        } else if (isRestRequest(request)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
        } else {
            super.commence(request, response, authException);
        }
    }

    /**
   * Checks if this is a X-domain pre-flight request.
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isPreflight(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod());
    }

    /**
     * Checks if it is a rest request
     * @param request
     * @return
     */
    protected boolean isRestRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return requestMatcher.matches(request);
    }
}
```

And then add the appropriate xml config

```
<security:http disable-url-rewriting="true" use-expressions="true" 
    entry-point-ref="ajaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
    <security:form-login 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1" 
        login-processing-url="/login/submit"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>

<bean id="ajaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.bmchild.service.user.AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/login" />
</bean>
```